# Como calcular tempo de execução no PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, runtime

Gostaria de saber quanto tempo leva para determinada função, laço de repetição, etc... ser executado. Recorri a função `microtime()`, porém fico um pouco perdido para saber com exatidão o tempo que foi gasto. E minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

1- Como posso converter microssegundos em segundos? De modo que fique um pouco legível e se ter uma noção o tempo que foi gasto durante a execução.

```
<?php

   $tempoInicial = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

   $var = 100000;

   for ($i=0; $i < $var; $i++) { 
      echo "$i -> ";
   }

   $tempoFinal = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

   $total = $tempoFinal - $tempoInicial;

   echo "Resultado: Tempo inicial: $tempoInicial <br> Tempo final: 
   $tempoFinal <br> Total: $total";
```

2- Há alguma ferramenta ou recurso disponível para o PHP que possa verificar em tempo real algo como a velocidade de execução do script, de uma função, laço de repetição, etc.

Comment: `microtime(true)` retorna algo como `1572433011.7642` (a quantidade de segundos mais as frações de segundos). Ao multiplicar por 1000 e arredondar, você obtém a quantidade de milissegundos (no caso, `1572433011764`), então para obter em segundos, bastaria dividir por 1000. É isso?

Answer (score 2):

Microssegundo (mS) é um múltiplo do segundo, uma unidade de tempo, com o prefixo pelo padrões base multiplicador micro (µ), igual a 0,000001 segundo(1 microssegundo = 1.0E-6 segundos). Logo, para obter o tempo em segundos, você deve dividir por 1000000.

A partir do **PHP 5** você pode usar `microtime` no início e fim do seu código:

```
<?php
    $inicio = microtime(true);
    sleep(1);
    $fim = microtime(true);
    $tempo = $fim - $inicio;
    printf("Processado em: %0.16f segundos", $tempo/1000000);
?>
```

**Veja funcionando:**
https://paiza.io/projects/udZy3WdDvQ4kYrUj7AGSSQ

A partir do **PHP 5.4.0** , não há necessidade de começar a hora de início, a `$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]` já a possui:

```
<?php
    sleep(1);
    $tempo = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
    printf("Processado em: %0.16f segundos", $tempo/1000000);
?>
```

**Veja Funcionando:** https://paiza.io/projects/JhDm9gJcBiFOu7hL_4ydtg

> Referências
>
> [Calculadora Conversão Microssegundos para Segundos](http://extraconversion.com/pt/tempo/microssegundos/microssegundos-para-segundos.html)
>
> [Documentação microtime PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php)
>
> [Como encontrar o tempo de execução do php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035859/how-to-find-php-execution-time)

Comment: Não quer colocar isso em algum lado a funcionar como o sandbox do PHP?

Answer (score -2):

Utilize `time()` em vez de `microtime()`